# How can I play Medal of Honor: Allied Assault (PC) on my 27" Intel Core i7 iMac?

Tags: pc, macos, vmware-fusion, medal-of-honor-allied-assault

I have the PC version of Medal of Honor: Allied Assault (MOH:AA) and I would like to play it on my 27" (Intel Core i7) iMac, how can I do this?

Searching only shows old PPC Mac binaries for running the game. 
I guess a Windows XP image in a VM (parallels / vmware-fusion) might work, but I'm concerned about performance.

Comment: For reference, here is a link to the 'Medal of Honor & Spearhead Combo 2.15b' PPC binary: http://www.macgamefiles.com/detail.php?item=17268

Comment: Thanks guys. I hadn't considered bootcamp,

I ended up using vmware-fusion and it runs great! I'm very happy with the performance with all game video settings turned up to max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have bootcamp consider that, otherwise shoot for parallels, I've never tried Vmware-fusion so I can't judge if it will really preform well for a game like MoH:Allied Assault.

Anyway, good luck with it, I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Bootcamp might be your best option.  I got Halflife 2 running pretty well in parallels, but it still runs better in bootcamp

Answer (score 0):

Running anything in a virtual machine means you are typically going to take a hit. VMWare has been doing a lot of work to get direct access to video cards and processors for performance gains, but this breaks the sandbox of a virtual image; so it's a difficult problem. They are working on it.

That said, the best you can hope for, for games that are not supported natively on Macs, is to run a virtual image (with VMWare as an example) and play the game in it like you would with any native PC. It may work great, it may not work on the lowest settings, you really just have to try it and find out.

Edit: Alternatively you can dual boot your machine, and boot into Windows whenever you want to play the game. This would eliminate the need for a VM.